# Python : SQLAlchemy getting stuck while writing dataframe to Postgres

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to pull data frm API and put it into Dataframe and write it into Postgres DB

This is the code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2
    
conn = db.connect()
pg_conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cur = pg_conn.cursor()
cur.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE schema1.table_1') 

 
response = requests.get(url, auth=(uname, pwd))
response_data = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response_data)
df.to_sql('table_1', con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False,schema='schema1')


pg_conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

Either it will get stuck at truncate table or at writing dataframe. What am i missing here ?

Comment: can you try by moving `pg_conn.commit() and cur.close()` above `response=requests.get(..` ?

Comment: From here [Truncate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html) "TRUNCATE acquires an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock on each table it operates on, which blocks all other concurrent operations on the table." So you need to `pg_conn.commit()` the `cur.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE schema1.table_1') ` before moving on to importing data into it.

Comment: When i do that, `truncate` table gets stuck when the table is empty. So I do `rollback` and everything works fine